# qtree not rendering left subtree

Tags: qtree

I am using the qtree package to try to render a tree.

```
\Tree [.+ [.+ 1 [.+ 2 3 ] ]
          \qroof{\Tree [.+ [.+ 2 4 ] 6 ] \qquad \Tree [.+ [.+ 3 5 ] 7 ] }.A
      ]
```

The code renders the following image. Note that the left (`[.+ 1 [.+ 2 3 ] ]`) subtree is completely absent.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong or could this be a qtree bug?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. It's always more helpful to post a complete compilable example  (like the one in my answer) rather than just a code fragment as you have done here.

Answer (score 1):

The `qtree` package is very old, and for most purposes there are better packages available. But the `qtree` `\Tree` command is not intended to be embedded in the way that you did in your example code, so I wouldn't call the behaviour you are seeing a bug. In fact, most of the tree drawing packages will not allow you to embed one tree inside the other in this way.

If you want to achieve the effect of embedding the trees, you could use `\savebox` to precompile the embedded trees. I've shown a solution using that method with `qtree`.

Personally, however, I would recommend using the `forest` package and drawing the roofed node manually rather than embedding trees (which isn't possible with `forest` either.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{qtree}
\newsavebox{\myA}
\newsavebox{\myB}
\begin{document}
\savebox\myA{\Tree [.+ [.+ 2 4 ] 6 ] }
\savebox\myB{\Tree [.+ [.+ 3 5 ] 7 ] }
\Tree [.+ [.+ 1 [.+ 2 3 ] ]
          \qroof{\usebox\myA\qquad\usebox\myB  }.A
      ]
\hfill
\begin{forest}
[+ [+ [1] [+ [2] [3] ] ]
           [A [+,name=A1 [+ [2] [4] ] [6] ]  [+,name=A2 [+ [3] [5] ] [7] ]
      ]]
\draw (A1.north)--(A2.north);
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]